# Chef to run a cookbook again

Tags: chef-infra

I have a recipe(say A), that includes a cookbook B, Also there is a recipe(say C) that includes this cookbook B again. Now if i make a recipe that includes both  A and C in the order. What will happen is that cookbook B will run before A and A will do its job. Now C will now call cookbook B which has already run so it will not run, so C will do its job without calling B before.

But for C to work correctly , A should have done its job after calling B and then C should rerun cookbook B.

So how to rerun the cookbook B in C again.

Comment: You're going against any system configuration management way. you're thinking in a provisioning manner, so either: 1) you're using the wrong tool, 2) You're have to rethink how you configure things.

Answer (score 4):

This thinking kind of violates the desired state approach. Recipes aren't run multiple times.

Chef's [custom resources or libraries](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources_notes.html) allow help you to create reusable functionality that is then used in recipes.

Comment: is there any i can restructure my code so that it will work?

Comment: I don't know your code and the problem you try to solve.. But anything is possible with code ;-) Please read the docs first.

Comment: if i do chef-client -o A; chef-client -o C; it will work ; so is there any way of achieving this flow?

Comment: That's not how chef is designed to work. Please get yourself familiar with its concepts first.

Comment: Instead of including recipes you probably want to make a Custom Resource and reference that in cookbooks A and C. Recipes are end states to achieve, resources are logical blocks to perform and can have properties passed in.

Comment: To echo what StephenKing said, recipes are not intended for multiple invocations, they define things in absolute terms and thus can only be run once. If you copy your recipe code into a custom resource and replace any node attributes with resource properties, it will probably just work though.